# What is the best way to display and apply filters to RAW images on macOS?

Tags: image, core-graphics, metalkit

I am creating a simple photo catalogue application for macOS to see whether the latest APIs can significantly improve performance of loading directories with large numbers of images.

So far it looks pretty promising and loading around 600 45MB RAW image thumbnails using `QLThumbnailGenerator` and `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL` is super fast allowing thumbnail images and image metadata to be displayed almost instantly.

Displaying these images in a NSCollectionView using a CALayer in the NSCollectionViewItem's view also appears to be extremely fast and scrolling is very smooth.

I did find that `QLThumbnailGenerator`seems to start failing after a few hundred images and starts returning error code 108 if I call the api in a continuous loop - I fixed that by calling `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` immediately after the thumbnail generator api call - so maybe there is a timing issue or not enough file handles or something if the api is called to quickly and for too long.

However I am still having trouble rendering a full sized image to the display - here I am using a NSScrollView with a layer backed NSView documentView.  Everything is super fast until the following call:

```
view.layer.contents = cgImage
```

And at this point the entire main thread hangs until the image has loaded - and this may take a few seconds.

Once it has loaded it's fine and zooming in and out by changing the documentView frame size is very fast - scrolling around the full size image is also super smooth without any of the typical hiccups.

Is there a way of loading these images without causing the UI to freeze ?

I've seen the recent WWDC2020 session where they demonstrate similar scrolling of large numbers of images but I haven't been able to find anything useful on loading large images other than CATiledLayer - but it's not really clear if that is the right answer for this problem.

The old Apple sample RawExpose seemed to be an option but most of that code is deprecated and it seems one has to use MetalKit not instead of GLKit - unfortunately there is no example of using MetaKit with Core Image that I can find.

FYI - I tried using some the new SwiftUI CollectionView and List but they seem to be significantly slower than AppKit and I found some of the collection view items never render - of course these could just be bugs in the macOS 11 beta.

Answer (score 0):

OK - well I finally figured it out and it's complicated but simple. It's complicated because there are so many options to choose from and so many outdated sample apps to look at.  In any event I think I have solved most if not all the issues related to using metal backed CALayers and rendering realtime updates of the images as CIFilter adjustments are applied.  There are many pieces to the puzzle and happy to share if anyone is looking for help.

Some key pointers:

1. I am using CAMetalLayer and NSView
2. I override the CAMetalLayer.display(layer:) method and call the layer.setNeedsDisplay() when the user slides an adjustment slider.
3. I chain together all the CIFilters, including the RAW filter created with CIFilter(imageUrl:)
4. Most importantly I use the RAW filters scaleFactor parameter to size the image - encountered major performance issues using any other method to resize the image for the views size
5. Don't expect high performance if the image is zoomed right in - 50% is seems to be the limit for 45megapixel RAW imaged from Nikon D850.

A short video of the result is here https://youtu.be/5wp0CIWAoIM